# IONIC 5 Cordova Plugin can build but not working when run android. It work only in -livereload

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

My IONIC 5 app using many cordova plugins.
The app working perfectly when I run

`ionic cordova run android -l`

But when I run

`ionic cordova run android`

The app can be built successfully but all cordova plugin is not run. Just like the cordova plugins do not contain in the app.

Please guild me to solve this issue, Thank you.

Below here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "videochat",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.6",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/base64-to-gallery": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/insomnia": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/lottie-splash-screen": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-ringtones": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/screenshot": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.24.0",
    "@ionic-native/vibration": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^9.2.0",
    "@ngxs/storage-plugin": "^3.6.2",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.6.2",
    "audiotoggle": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": "^0.7.0",
    "compare-func": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-audiotoggle": "^1.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-carthage-support": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-insomnia": "^4.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-iosrtc": "^6.0.13",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-native-ringtones": "^0.2.5",
    "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": "^3.0.9",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-vibration": "^3.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.7.2",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "extsprintf": "^1.4.0",
    "firebase": "^7.19.1",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "lottie-web": "^5.7.3",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "native-run": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-lottie": "^0.3.2",
    "ngx-lottie": "^6.4.0",
    "properties-parser": "^0.3.1",
    "qrcode": "^1.4.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.900",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.6",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.1.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot": "^0.1.6",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-base64-to-gallery": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-android-enumeratedevices": "git+https://github.com/OpenVidu/cordova-plugin-android-enumeratedevices.git",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-crop": "^0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^7.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "^1.2.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.7.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "openvidu-browser": "2.14.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "xcode": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-enumeratedevices": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-iosrtc": {
        "MANUAL_INIT_AUDIO_DEVICE": "FALSE"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-audiotoggle": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": {},
      "cordova-plugin-native-ringtones": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-insomnia": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {
        "ANDROID_FCM_VERSION": "19.0.0",
        "ANDROID_GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION": "3.5.3",
        "ANDROID_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION": "4.3.3",
        "ANDROID_DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ICON": "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot": {},
      "cordova-base64-to-gallery": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-crop": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-vibration": {}
    },
    "platforms": []
  }
}
```

Below here is my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.myapp.chat" ios-CFBundleVersion="0.1.11" version="0.0.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Coach</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardResize" value="true" />
    <preference name="KeyboardResizeMode" value="native" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <resource-file src="resources/raw/incoming-call.mp3" target="incoming-call.mp3" />
    <platform name="android">
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <config-file mode="merge" parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        </config-file>
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="UseSwiftLanguageVersion" value="4.2" />
        <preference name="UseLegacySwiftLanguageVersion" value="true" />
        <preference name="AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures" value="true" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
        <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
        <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <hook src="hooks/iosrtc-swift-support.js" type="after_platform_add" />
        <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>อนุญาตเข้าถึงกล้องของคุณ</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>อนุญาตเข้าถึงอัลบั้มรูปภาพของคุณ</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>อนุญาตเข้าถึงอัลบั้มรูปภาพของคุณ</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSContactsUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>OpenVidu needs access to contacts</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>OpenVidu needs access to your microphone</string>
        </config-file>
        <icon height="216" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-108@2x.png" width="216" />
        <splash height="2688" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2688h~iphone.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2688h~iphone.png" width="2688" />
        <splash height="1792" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-1792h~iphone.png" width="828" />
        <splash height="828" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-1792h~iphone.png" width="1792" />
    </platform>
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100" sessionid="fc4d5416" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-iosrtc" spec="^6.0.11" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.178:8100" sessionid="aa93b197" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-enumeratedevices" spec="../cordova-plugin-android-enumeratedevices" />
    <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^3.0.1">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Comment: Please add the error message that you are getting in your question. Also, by looking at your config.xml file, it looks like the camera plugin is not installed. Try reinstalling it & verify that its entry exist in package.json & config.xml

Comment: Another thing that is very concerning is that you have most of your cordova plugin dependencies declared under `devDependencies` in your package.json file..Which is not right... These plugin files will not get copied over once you build your application..Move these to `dependencies`

Answer (score 3):

After I spend more than 10 hours to fix the issue.
I found the error log in Android Studio:

```
gap_init called from restricted origin: app://localhost
```

I compare with another Ionic app, the origin is "http://localhost"

So I change the origin to "http://localhost"

I know that this solution is not the right way to do. But it can solve the problem for now.

Anyone has a better way to assign origin in `config.xml` ?

[image: Fix the origin in CordovaBridge.java]

Comment: I was struggling with the barcode scanner plugin not lanched on android. Your post showed me the way to solve my issue. To allow origin you have to add this in the config.xml `<allow-navigation href="app://localhost" />`